# Permutations based on sum without limiting number of items permuted

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

```
import itertools as itt

layer_thickness=[1,2,3,4,5]
permu= itt.permutations(layer_thickness,5)
permu_list=list(permu)
for i in permu_list:
    if sum(i)==15:
        print(i)
```

Here, I want permutations of the elements in the `layer_thickness` and those sum of the permutations should be to `5`. But the number of elements in prmutation is not constrained by any limit unless it gives the desired sum.

`1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 , 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1, etc`  are should be an element also.

what modifications should I do to achieve that?

Comment: I can't quite get your question. Can you please add the expected aoutput?

Comment: You definitely do not want to generate a list of all permutations that start with 15 _ones_ (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1) and stop with (5,5,5) to sum up to 15 - those are far !!! too many illegal ones that get discarded. The trick is to code smart, not create all and filter - your computers memory can not hold all those permutations.

Comment: @PatrickArtner , I think that's exactly what I wanted :D ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant create all permutation as list for any total - it will simply hug too much memory:

- *Assuming `[1,2,3,4,5]` as numbers, `1` is your lowest element.*
- *Assuming you want to reach a `total = 15` - your "biggest" solution is `(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)`.*
- *To create all possible permutation of 5 numbers over 15 places you need to create `15**5` list entries: `15**5 = 2.562.890.625` possible number permutations*

Storing each combination as 1 byte this would need `2.56 Terabyte` of ram. Doubt you got that much.

---

The best you can do is to generate only numbers that work and quit out as soon as you reached your total. To do that for a fixed number set you can start with this question: [Finding all possible combinations of numbers to reach a given sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum)

Using that and provide a "maximized" list of your numbers that can be added up to achieve your goal might lead to something:

> ```
> def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[], partial_sum=0):
>     if partial_sum == target:
>         yield partial
>     if partial_sum >= target:
>         return
>     for i, n in enumerate(numbers):
>         remaining = numbers[i + 1:]
>         yield from subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n], partial_sum + n)
> ```
>
> Credit:   https://stackoverflow.com/a/4633515/7505395

```
def calc_nums_for_permutate(nums, total):
    """Creates a list of numbers from num - each single number is added as
    many times as itself fits into total"""
    return [n for n in nums for _ in range(total//n)]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    total = 15
    
    print( *subset_sum( calc_nums_for_permutate(nums, total), total))
```

This will not work for all and any inputs - good luck with your runtime, this will still work reasonably well for a `total = 10` - for a `total = 15`  it will take more time then I needed to format/copy paste and formulate this answer here.

Comment: Thanks for answering. It is so much helpful, But here, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2856866 I found that only 13624 solutions for this instead of 2.562.890.625.